# Parameterising and finding surface area

Tags: surface-integrals, parametrization

The question:
Consider the surface given by $x^2 +y^2 =z^2$ where $0\leq z\leq1$

(a) Parametrise the surface.

(b) Use surface integrals of the first kind to compute its area. Explain your work.

So far solution was

(a) $x=z\cos \theta, y=z\sin \theta, z=z$

$r^2\cos ^2\theta + r^2\sin ^2\theta =z^2$

$r^2=z^2$ so $z=r$ with $0\leq r\leq1$

(b) $S=\int^{2\pi}_{0} \int^{1}_{0}rdrd\theta $

But I don't think that's the correct integral, any help would be greatly appreciated thank you

Comment: Your surface is a right circular cone of unit height and radius $1.$ Thus the slant edge is $\sqrt 2$ units long and so the surface area is $$π\sqrt 2.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the standard expression below for the surface integral,

$$ I=\int_S \sqrt{1+(z_x^{'})^2+(z_y^{'})^2 }dxdy$$

where, use the given surface parametrization $x^2+y^2=z^2$ directly, the integrand is

$$ \sqrt{1+(z_x^{'})^2+(z_y^{'})^2 }= \sqrt{1+(-x/z)^2+(-y/z)^2}=\sqrt{2}$$

Because of the circular boundary in the $xy$-plane,
convert to the polar coordinates for the integration,

$$ I=\int_S \sqrt{2}dxdy=\sqrt{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 rdrd\theta=\sqrt{2}\pi$$

Comment: I think you wanted to write instead $x^2+y^2=\color{red}{z^2}.$

Comment: Thankswill make the correction

Comment: $\frac {\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac {y}{z}$

Answer (score 0):

This should help with parameterization:

[image]